# Nivo Slider - Changing DIV background color

Tags: jquery, slider, nivo-slider

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the CSS of another element (for example body) as the Nivo slider transitions through the slides. If it were simply hyperlinks, I could use JQuery to apply the additional CSS on click, but I'm not sure of where to start having it done this way.

Basically I'm looking to change the background color of another DIV as the slides change. I could setup a basic loop in JQuery, but I was hoping to have it tied into Nivo (or any slider for that matter).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on a Nivo div that changes when the slide changes.  Then you can add in your own code to set the color of your div. Here is a quick example:

```
$('.nivoSlider').css("background-image").change(function() {
  alert('DO STUFF HERE');
});
```

I may not have the selector correct, but it should get you in the right direction.